# templateLink does not exixst

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-data-factory

So I am trying to deploy [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.compute/vms-with-selfhost-integration-runtime) script from Github. What it should do is deploy a VM to my existing resource group. Then it should install an Integration Runtime on it and link it to my existing Data Factory. The part that is not working is installing the IR in the first place.

In the main.bicep file, there is the following parameter:

`@description('The base URI where artifacts required by this template are located.')`

`param _artifactsLocation string = deployment().properties.templateLink.uri`

The error that I am getting is, that the "templateLink" doesn't exist. I am guessing it has something to do with me deploying the script locally, however I cannot change said parameter because I don't understand what it is doing in the first place.

So how do I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to deploy this bicep file from github using this url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/quickstarts/microsoft.compute/vms-with-selfhost-integration-runtime/main.bicep

instead of cloning and deploying locally, that way it will have `templateLink` property will exist on the deployment

Comment: But what if I need to deploy it on my own (let's say from DevOps eg.). How would I change the templateLink to make it work?

Comment: same way. upload it to a storage account and call it from there

Comment: I have everything there and I still get the same error

Comment: since you dont provide links\commands how you are calling the template its impossible to tell what is wrong, but templateLink property does exist: `The templateLink property is only returned when linking to a remote template with a URL. If you're using a local template, that property isn't available.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#using-variables-to-link-templates